# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'.... how can i resolve that?

Tags: python, dataframe, append

i have a question.
in the code below, i can't make a plot.
how can i resolve that?
give me some advice,please.

````
port = rp.Portfolio(returns=rets)
method_mu = 'hist'
method_cov = 'hist'
port.assets_stats(method_mu=method_mu, method_cov=method_cov)
model = 'Classic'
rm = 'MV'
obj = 'MinRisk'
hist = True
rf = 0
l = 0
w = port.optimization(model=model, rm=rm, obj=obj, rf=rf, l=l, hist=hist)
ax = rp.plot_bar(w=w)```


AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
````

Comment: If you're using a library that relies on pandas, you may need to open an issue so they get rid of append (see linked q/a).